# Why does LoginView behave as though I am not logged in?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, loginview

I have a site created in Visual Studio 2010, when I run the site in 2010 the LoginView control fires properly, detects that I am logged in, and displays my domain\username.  However, when I run the site in Visual Studio 2013 Pro the LoginView control displays the Anonymous template.  Why does that happen?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Could you make sure `<authentication mode="XXX">` inside web.config is same in both VS?

Comment: It is the same, both have `<authentication mode="Windows">`.  Would opening a solution from 2010 in 2013 cause web.config to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. Instead, it'll help you debug why it is not working.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var id = (FormsIdentity) User.Identity;
        var ticket = id.Ticket;
        sb.Append("Authenticated");
        sb.Append("<br/>CookiePath: " + ticket.CookiePath);
        sb.Append("<br/>Expiration: " + ticket.Expiration);
        sb.Append("<br/>Expired: " + ticket.Expired);
        sb.Append("<br/>IsPersistent: " + ticket.IsPersistent);
        sb.Append("<br/>IssueDate: " + ticket.IssueDate);
        sb.Append("<br/>Name: " + ticket.Name);
        sb.Append("<br/>UserData: " + ticket.UserData);
        sb.Append("<br/>Version: " + ticket.Version);
        Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
    }
    else
        Label1.Text = "Not Authenticated";
}
```